# Wildcard in request filter for Stackdriver Trace Analysis Report?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'd like to create a Stackdriver Trace Analysis Report for a particular request that has the url pattern `/foo/*/bar`, that is, a middle wildcard of the url. Is that possible?

When I try to create one with that pattern, I get an error:

```
The request will not produce a useful report because it had less than 100 traces. Create a new report with a longer time range or less-restrictive filter.
```

But there's certainly many requests that fit this pattern.

[image: screenshot of stackdriver tracing new report request page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter syntax lets you define when matches are exact, or when they are prefix tests so it is not possible to use a wildcard in the middle of the filter string.

You can find more information on each parameter [HERE](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/finding-traces#filter_traces)

*All matches are case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks Ernesto. I wish they had either a suffix test or middle wildcard. It helps for RESTful urls that are an action on a resource, e.g., '/widgets/{widget_id}/action', where I want to analyze specifically that action on all widgets.